# Filling out Object Properties with default values Recursive

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, objectinstantiation

I want to populate the object's properties with some dummy data. Here is my code but it always returns null.

```
private static object InsertDummyValues(object obj)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof (String))
            {
                property.SetValue(obj, property.Name.ToString(), null);
            }

            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Boolean))
            {
                property.SetValue(obj, true, null);
            }

            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Decimal))
            {
                property.SetValue(obj, 23.5, null);
            }

            else
            {
                // create the object 
                var o = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(property.PropertyType.Name));
                property.SetValue(obj,o,null);
                if (o != null) 
                   return InsertDummyValues(o);
            }
        }
    }

    return obj; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You told it to `return null;`, try `return obj;` instead.

Also, remove the `return` from the `if (o != null) return InsertDummyValues(o);` line.

To answer your question in the comment...

```
else if (property.PropertyType.IsArray)
{
    property.SetValue(obj, Array.CreateInstance(type.GetElementType(), 0), null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I remove the above things. One problem I am encountering now is that there is a collection (array) of some class inside the original object. And the Activator.CreateInstance fails to create object of an array.

Comment: I found Array.CreateInstance but is takes size. The size is not known at this point!

Comment: Array.CreateInstance did not work out because it is already an array.

Comment: I've added to my answer, if it is dummy data, just make it a zero element array, or you could build those out as well

Comment: If the array is already initialized, then just skip it, or you could use reflection to get the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `return obj;` at the end of the `if (obj != null)` block...

Comment: I added it but it should return the original object that was passed filled with all the properties. Some properties are classes having their own properties.

Comment: Thanks! I remove the above things. One problem I am encountering now is that there is a collection (array) of some class inside the original object. And the Activator.CreateInstance fails to create object of an array.