# "Nullable object must have a value" exception after checking for null on a non-primitive/non-struct object

Tags: c#, lambda, devart

I'm getting `Nullable object must have a value after checking for null` on a regular object, after a null check. I've found various questions, mostly regarding linq-to-sql, having the same problem but always with nullable primitive types (as in `bool?` or `DateTime?`).

The line causing the exception in my case looks like this:

```
myDataContext.Orders.Where(y => customer.Address == null || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.Address.Street) || y.Customers.Addresses.Street == customer.Address.Street)))
```

`customer` class looks like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    private Address address = null;
    public Address Address{get{return address;} set{address=value;}}
}
```

`address` property looks like this:

```
public class Address
{
    private string street = null;
    public string Street{get{return street ;} set{street =value;}}
}
```

If I replace above code line with this:

```
string custStreet = null;
if (customer.Address != null)
{
    custStreet = customer.Address.Street;
}

myDataContext.Orders.Where(y =>(customer.Address == null || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(custStreet) || y.Customers.Addresses.Street == custStreet)))
```

it runs fine. I don't undestand the reason for that. I also don't want to define countless variables before executing the Lambda statement itself.

Please also note that above Lambda statement is part of a much bigger Lambda `Where` clause that contains a few more of such statements. I know I could work with Expression Trees but having coded this far, I really don't want to switch now.

**edit**

as the question was answered, I'm going to tell you how I worked around it: I build myself a recursive property initializer. Everything that is not a string, a list/array or a primitive type is thrown against the `Activator` class. I got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1539742/937093) and made a few changes to it (basically, ignore everything that doesn't need to be initialized and instead of `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(property.PropertyType.Name));` I used `Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType));` I'm not even sure if the version used in the original question would work or why anyone would want to use it.)

Comment: Check the exception stack trace - it might be a bug in the query provider you are using.

Comment: That line is incomplete though. What is it? An `if`? A boolean assigned to a var? On that note... I don't see any lambda expressions in there. That's just some boolean operations.

Comment: @IvanStoev `at Devart.Data.Linq.Engine.bp.c.a(Expression A_0)` it's completely useless. It could be a problem with the provider, though.

Comment: @Nyerguds not sure what you mean with the first part 'What is it?'. In any case, I added some code to the line so it makes more sense, I guess. Even though it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: That's what I had in mind. Most likely the provider is trying to reduce constant predicates and does that incorrectly.

Comment: Hmm. So the intent is that if either `customer.Address` or `customer.Address.Street` are null, it would just return everything from `Orders`? An optional filter? Could be it has a problem with never getting to the part where y is actually used, then. But, certainly an odd case.

Comment: I don;t think you've shown what is _actually_ causing the exception.  You do not have any nullable value types in that expression.  Can you post the _entire_ method instead of just snippets?

Comment: @Nyerguds correct. It's basically a large statement for a UI search function. And it definetly hits the `y`, you can see that in the later part of my question where I provide a workaround for the solution that works.

Comment: @IvanStoev But it's *not* doing it incorrectly.

Comment: @DStanley that's the entire point: I've no primitive, nullable types in that entire statement, anywhere. Well, in theory I've them but I removed them from the statement for now. Exception remains. And it's caused by that line, look at the second part of my question. I explain how I can work around that bug in theory and that it works if I do that.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler You don't have nullable value type, but you do have nullable types, and you're evaluating them to a value when they're null, hence the error.

Comment: @Servy I disagree. The query provider is not forced to translate the exact expression to SQL. It can see that `customer.Address == null` is a constantly true and eliminate the whole `Where`. Similar to what you'll do manually using `if (condition) query = query.Where(...)`. The problem is though that they **don't** do such optimizations.

Comment: @IvanStoev Saying that it erroring is incorrect is to say that it's *obligated* to make such an optimization.  It is not.  You'll find that pretty much all query providers, as a rule, won't do much at all in the way of optimizations, and they certainly aren't *expected* to perform them.

Comment: @Servy Agreed. Probably I didn't state it correctly - it would be nice if they do that because I'm seeing a lot of similar questions on SO (not NRE related) - for instance [LINQ to Entities conditionals give weird results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761694/linq-to-entities-conditionals-give-weird-results) and in general for building dynamic `Where` clauses. While the general answer is - don't do that, use `if`s or predicate builders, it would be nice if there is a (sort of) general solution. I'm thinking of doing something in that regard myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the expression `customer.Address.Street` *must* be evaluated to its value *before the query can be translated into SQL.  That expression cannot be left in the underlying SQL for the database to possibly, or possibly not, evaluate to a value.  The query provider has to evaluate it unconditionally in order to determine what the SQL should look like.  So yes, you do need to perform the null check *outside* of the expression.  There are of course any number of ways you could do so, but that null checking logic *does* need to be outside of the expression the query provider translates.

Comment: that'd be exactly what I'm fearing. But shouldn't the provider see that my local `Address` object is null and just ignore everything after the `||` when translating to SQL?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler The purpose of the provider is to translate the entire expression into SQL, not to try to evaluate the expression on items that it doesn't even have.  This isn't linq to objects, it's not executing the code as code, it needs to translate *the whole thing* into SQL.

Comment: but that's my point exactly: It's not running into a `null` on the database. My local `Address` object that the provider has to know to build the SQL statement is null. Not anything on the database. The `customer` object is defined and declared outside of the Lambda statement.

Comment: Ah, right. This isn't just linq; it's an actual database query, isn't it? It's not running into null on the database, it's running into null in the data required to build the query.

Comment: @Nyerguds the result would be a SQL statement, yes.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Yes, that's correct.  The query provider needs to evaluate `customer.Address.Street` in order to use that value in the generated SQL statement that is sent to the database, because that value cannot be evaluated by the database.  A null value is de-referenced when attempting to evaluate that expression and generate the SQL, hence the error.

Comment: @Servy ah, thank you for that explanation. #Answered

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what I wrote in the comments, the problem is that query providers does **not** even try to reduce the predicate expressions by eliminating the constant parts. As @Servy correctly stated in the comments, they are not forced to do that, and speaking generally there might be a technical reason not doing it, but in reality people tend to use such conditions in their query expressions and expect them to work as **if** they are evaluated in LINQ to Objects.

I've seen many questions with similar usage, the last being [LINQ to Entities conditionals give weird results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761694/linq-to-entities-conditionals-give-weird-results), and the "standard" comment/answer is - use chained `Where` with `if`s or some predicate builder. Then I start thinking - ok, the providers don't do that, so why don't we do that ourselves then - after all, we are developers and can write (some) code. So I've ended up with the following extension method which uses `ExpressionVisitor` to modify the query expression tree. I was thinking to post it to the linked question, but since I've get somehow involved in this thread, here you go:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ReduceConstPredicates<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        var reducer = new ConstPredicateReducer();
        var expression = reducer.Visit(source.Expression);
        if (expression == source.Expression) return source;
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
    }

    class ConstPredicateReducer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private int evaluateConst;
        private bool EvaluateConst { get { return evaluateConst > 0; } }
        private ConstantExpression TryEvaluateConst(Expression node)
        {
            evaluateConst++;
            try { return Visit(node) as ConstantExpression; }
            catch { return null; }
            finally { evaluateConst--; }
        }
        protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
        {
            if (EvaluateConst || node.Type == typeof(bool))
            {
                var operandConst = TryEvaluateConst(node.Operand);
                if (operandConst != null)
                {
                    var result = Expression.Lambda(node.Update(operandConst)).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
                    return Expression.Constant(result, node.Type);
                }
            }
            return EvaluateConst ? node : base.VisitUnary(node);
        }
        protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
        {
            if (EvaluateConst || node.Type == typeof(bool))
            {
                var leftConst = TryEvaluateConst(node.Left);
                if (leftConst != null)
                {
                    if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.AndAlso)
                        return (bool)leftConst.Value ? Visit(node.Right) : Expression.Constant(false);
                    if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.OrElse)
                        return !(bool)leftConst.Value ? Visit(node.Right) : Expression.Constant(true);
                    var rightConst = TryEvaluateConst(node.Right);
                    if (rightConst != null)
                    {
                        var result = Expression.Lambda(node.Update(leftConst, node.Conversion, rightConst)).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
                        return Expression.Constant(result, node.Type);
                    }
                }
            }
            return EvaluateConst ? node : base.VisitBinary(node);
        }
        protected override Expression VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression node)
        {
            if (EvaluateConst || node.Type == typeof(bool))
            {
                var testConst = TryEvaluateConst(node.Test);
                if (testConst != null)
                    return Visit((bool)testConst.Value ? node.IfTrue : node.IfFalse);
            }
            return EvaluateConst ? node : base.VisitConditional(node);
        }
        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (EvaluateConst || node.Type == typeof(bool))
            {
                var expressionConst = node.Expression != null ? TryEvaluateConst(node.Expression) : null;
                if (expressionConst != null || node.Expression == null)
                {
                    var result = Expression.Lambda(node.Update(expressionConst)).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
                    return Expression.Constant(result, node.Type);
                }
            }
            return EvaluateConst ? node : base.VisitMember(node);
        }
        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            if (EvaluateConst || node.Type == typeof(bool))
            {
                var objectConst = node.Object != null ? TryEvaluateConst(node.Object) : null;
                if (objectConst != null || node.Object == null)
                {
                    var argumentsConst = new ConstantExpression[node.Arguments.Count];
                    int count = 0;
                    while (count < argumentsConst.Length && (argumentsConst[count] = TryEvaluateConst(node.Arguments[count])) != null)
                        count++;
                    if (count == argumentsConst.Length)
                    {
                        var result = Expression.Lambda(node.Update(objectConst, argumentsConst)).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
                        return Expression.Constant(result, node.Type);
                    }
                }
            }
            return EvaluateConst ? node : base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }
    }
}
```

With that extension method in place, all you need is to insert `.ReduceConstPredicates()` at the end of your queries (before `AsEnumerable()`, `ToList` and similar):

```
var query = myDataContext.Orders
    .Where(y => customer.Address == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.Address.Street) || y.Customers.Addresses.Street == customer.Address.Street)
    .ReduceConstPredicates();
```